# Jquery Datepicker - css

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-datepicker, datapicker, jquerydatetimepicker

Is there any way to show month input type as number (i.e textbox with up and down arrow) instead of dropdown.

Please help on this. See my demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sharmilashree/VBGKU/1067/

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar tr {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #F6F6F6
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify if you want to adjust each part, day, month, & year, with a Spinner? See more: http://jqueryui.com/spinner/ Or are you asking about using HTML5 `input type='number'` specifically for the Month in the datepicker display?

Comment: Also see: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Comment: for year alone i need to show HTML5 input type='number' control

Comment: Ok, so not Month, but only Year? and not be a dropdown, but to be a spinner. Do you want to use HTML5 element `input type='number'` or the jQuery UI Spinner?

Comment: please find the image i have attached.  all things i have done.. only thing is need to set year text box with up and down arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be a difficult workaround. This is not easily done. Here is what I have so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ge6zh5es/6/

**HTML**

```
<p>Date:
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="Highlighted" />
</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var minYear = 2006,
    maxYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  maxYear++;
  var $dp = $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    yearRange: minYear + ':' + maxYear,
  });
  $dp.datepicker("setDate", "0");

  function changeSpinner($dpObj) {
    var $yearSpin = $("<input>");
    $yearSpin.addClass("ui-datepicker-year");
    $yearSpin.attr({
      type: "number",
      min: minYear,
      max: maxYear,
      value: new Date().getFullYear()
    }).data("handler", "selectYear").data("event", "change");
    $yearSpin.on("change", function() {
      console.log("Spinner Change Event.");
      var pDate = $dpObj.datepicker("getDate");
      pDate.setFullYear(parseInt(this.value));
      console.log("New Date: " + pDate);
      $dpObj.datepicker("setDate", pDate);
    });
    console.info("Created Spinner: ", $yearSpin);
    $dpObj.datepicker("widget").find(".ui-datepicker-year").replaceWith($yearSpin);
  }

  $("#datepicker").click(function() {
    changeSpinner($dp);
  }).change(function() {
    changeSpinner($db);
  });
});
```

This works the first time only. The datepicker itself does not have any events I can hook into to perform the replacement each time. I also have to add in some functions to get this new element to function properly with the datepicker.

I am considering removing the title bar items and separating them. I will update this answer with more details. Another option is to hide the `select` element and place a spinner over it. This spinner then changes the select element.

Comment: Thanks Twisty for your help. First time its look good and if the same remains whole process it will be great. I will try something from end also with your input meanwhile. If you got any solution please share 
 Thanks in advance..